# Large mesh problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, camera

[image: like this]Hi! I generate a landscape. So it is large, about 2000m. But in my camera view, it's not showing it as if there is nothing. And in my viewpoint, it only shows half of it.

Comment: maybe in the N panel > View, play with the Clip Start and End?

Comment: At view point it helped but in camera mod it's still the same

Comment: You also need to set the camera clipping values, select it and go in the Camera panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. Select your Camera in the scene
2. Go to Camera settings in the Properties tab
3. Tweak the `End` value to fit your needs

Comment: For the viewport, there is a similar setting. Open the side panel of the viewport (N key), select *View tab* and there is *View > (Clip) End*. You need to change this setting for each viewport. Every workspace (Layout, Modeling, Sculpting, UV Editing, ...) has its own viewport.